# Cadastrar dados usando ComboBox

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando criar uma imobiliária On-Line, ja consegui construir a estrutua, porém não tenho ideia de como cadastrar os Estados, Cidades e Bairros dos mesmo usando um ComboBox.

Para aqueles que puderem dar uma analisada eu deixo o endereço http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/ para ver que o ComboBox esta funcionando, pois cadastrei diretamente no BD os dados de um imóvel para teste no estado do Rio de Janeiro.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ideia de como cadastrar os anúncios dos imóveis com o ComboBox, ou de outra maneira ficarei muito agradecido.

Abaixo relaciono o código que criei e só consegui cadastrar o código do estado, nome do estado e a Sigla do estado.

Primeira fase: Selecionando o estado.

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='cadastrar_anuncio_2.php?cod_estado=$dp'</script>";
        }
        ?>
        <form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Selecione o estado de origem do Imóvel</label><br /><br />
        <select name="cod_estado">
        <?php
        include 'conexao.php';
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados ORDER BY nome_estado ASC");
        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $estados =  $res['cod_estado'];?>"><?php echo $estados =  $res['nome_estado'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select><br /><br />
        <input class="input" type="submit" name="enter" value="Avançar"/>
        </form>
```

Segunda fase: Gravando dados do estado.

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
            echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='cadastrar_anuncio_3.php?cod_estado=$dp'</script>";
        }
        ?>

        <form name="cadastrar" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <?php
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
        include "conexao.php";
        $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados WHERE cod_estado = '$cod_estado'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){
            $nome_estado = $_POST['nome_estado'];
            $uf = $_POST['uf']; 
            $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];  

            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO anuncio VALUES ('NULL', '$cod_estado', '$nome_estado', '$uf',  '$cod_cidade', '$nome_cidade', '$cod_bairro', '$nome_bairro', '$foto01')")or die(mysql_error());
        if($insert == ''){
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Erro ao cadastrar Anuncio!!!');
            </script>";
        }else{
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cadastrar_anuncio_3.php?cod_estado=".$cod_estado."'>
            <script language='javascript'>
            window.alert('Cidade cadastrada com sucesso!!!');
            </script>";
        }}
        $dp =  $_POST['cod_estado'];
        include 'conexao.php';
            $uf = $_GET['uf'];
            $nome_estado = $_GET['nome_estado'];
            $cod_estado = $_GET['cod_estado'];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estados WHERE cod_estado = '$cod_estado'");
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        ?>  
        <input size="1" type="text" name="cod_estado" value="<?php echo $res['cod_estado']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="20" type="text" name="nome_estado" value="<?php echo $res['nome_estado']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input size="1" type="text" name="uf" value="<?php echo $res['uf']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" />
        </form>
```

Dai em diante empaquei, não sei mais como prosseguir.
Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz, ficarei grato.

Abraços à todos.

Comment: Sergio, não sei bem se entendi a sua pergunta, do que exatamente você precisa? De uma melhor maneira de procurar os imóveis? Qual o seu problema exatamente, é com relação a estrutura de código dos imóveis? Sempre fiz esse tipo de cadastro no banco de dados da seguinte maneira, uma tabela de estado e outra de municípios, ai em cada anúncio teria o cadastro do bairro, para a fazer a busca. Exemplo da estrutura aqui, mas sem o país: http://samus.com.br/web/site/artigo-todas_as_cidades_do_brasil_atualizado_e_com_acentos

Comment: Olá Ruggi, é o seguinte, eu estou tentando fazer um site para um amigo que é corretor de imóveis, ele gostaria de cadastrar os imóveis no proprio site.
Mas eu não estou conseguindo cadastrar os imóveis de acordo com os estados, cidades e bairros.
Exemplo: Uma casa em São Paulo, na cidade de Araraquara e no bairro Centro, eu teria que cadastra-los com os codigo de cada respectivo estado, cidade e bairro, é isso que eu não estou conseguindo puxar do comboBox, já que nele eu tenho todos os código de estados, cidades e bairros.
Será que eu consegui me fazer entender...rsrsrs...

Comment: Continuando... Eu cheguei a cadastrar o código do estado, o nome do estado e a sigla do estado, porém empaquei, não sei como dar continuidade no cadastro da Cidade e do Bairro, puxando do ComboBox.
Eu publiquei o código usado para cadastrar o estado para que possa ser feito a busca do imóvel.... Pô parece que enrolei mais ainda...
Bem é isso espero que tenha conseguido me fazer entender.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem seu código, mas você pode utilizar a tag `select` dentro do html, atribuindo `values` a cada item, depois, se quiser, por usar um `if`, atribuindo um valor mais completo a cada item do `combobox`, ainda inclui um método bem simples de inserção deste valor em uma tabela, assim:

**HTML**

```
<form action="POST" action="index.php"> 
<select name="estado">
  <option value="rj">rio de janeiro</option>
  <option value="sp">são paulo</option>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php
$local = $_POST['estado'];
if ($local == rj){
  $local = "Rio de Janeiro";
  echo"$local";/*aqui retornaria Rio de janeiro*/
}elseif ($local == sp){
  $local = "São Paulo";
  echo"$local";/*aqui retornaria São Paulo*/
  $insere = "NSERT INTO tabela (local) VALUES ('$local')";
  $insere_query = 'mysql_query('$insere')';
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua atenção ao meu problema Jorge, vou tentar fazer com o seu raciocínio, posto o resultado que conseguir ou mesmo para tirar as dúvidas caso surjam. Mais uma vez BRIGADÃO.